# Check if a table exists

Tags: qt, sqlite

I am using this `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = "table" AND name = 'create_organization';` to check if the table named create_organization exists  and it works.However i would like to use qt to find that out.I am trying

```
 QSqlQuery query;
    QString tableName = "employee_datastores";
    QString sqlQuery = QString("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type =:table AND name = %1 ").arg(tableName);
    query.prepare(sqlQuery);
    query.bindValue(":table", "table");
    query.exec();
    int fieldNo = query.record().indexOf("employee_datastore_name");
    while (query.next()) {
        QString employee_ds_name = query.value(fieldNo).toString();
        qDebug() << "Table Name" << employee_ds_name ;
    }
```

but it does not work.

Comment: How does "not work" manifest?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Does QSqlDatabase::tables() give you what you want? For example you could try:

```
if ( database.tables().contains( QLatin1String("employee_datastores") ) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could fix it like this:

```
QString sqlQuery = QString("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type =:table AND name = '%1' ").arg(tableName);
query.prepare(sqlQuery);
query.bindValue(":table", "table");
query.exec();
```

But why mix bind values and "dumb" string replacement?

```
QString sqlQuery = QString("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type =:table AND name = :tablename ");
query.prepare(sqlQuery);
query.bindValue(":table", "table");
query.bindValue(":tablename", tableName);
query.exec();
```

Comment: I creating several tables and the tablename is the input of a qlineedit.

Comment: All the more reason to use bind parameters, less risk of SQL injection.

Comment: After running this, what do you actually check on `query` to see if the table exists or not? New question on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603109/

Answer (score 0):

This solved it.Thanks Mat.

```
QSqlQuery query;
    QString tableName = "structure";
    QString sqlQuery = QString("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type =:table AND name = '%1' ").arg(tableName);
    query.prepare(sqlQuery);
    query.bindValue(":table", "table");
    query.exec();
    int fieldNo = query.record().indexOf("name");
    while (query.next()) {
        QString _name = query.value(fieldNo).toString();
        qDebug() << "Table Name" << _name ;
    }
```

Comment: are you saying it is actually better to go through a full SELECT query rather than just check if the table exists as per the other answer by @jedillama?

Comment: the answer by @jediLLama is not the one you accepted to this question, yet you recommend it as the best choice

Comment: It was long ago when i accepted the answer.I have now accepted jedi's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use database.tables(QSql::AllTables) this will show you all the tables including master. Just a small edit to the correct answer: my edit is (QSql::AllTables)

```
if ( database.tables(QSql::AllTables).contains( QLatin1String("employee_datastores") ) {
... }
```